# echo array from mysql into <option> value

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me, I'm inserting the array (11,7,10) into a table.

Now i want to echo this data:

[click here to show table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuQUN.jpg)

```html
like this structure iwant to make it
<select>
<option value="11">11- HbA1C</option>
<option value="7">10- O"Solivan Test</option>
<option value="10">7- Randam Blood Glucose</option>
</select>
/////////////////////////////////////
table==>
id name date re_doctor  sex age  no_ana  name_pr
11 aaaa 17/04/2017    Female    11,10,7  11- HbA1C,10- O"Solivan Test,7- Randam Blood Gluco.

////////////////////////////////////////////////
my code :-
<?
$qqq=$_GET['n'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `profile` where id ='$qqq'"; // select only the username field from the table "users_table"
$result = mysql_query($sql); // process the query

$username_array = array(); // start an array

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ // cycle through each record returned
  $array1[] = $row[6]; // get the username field and add to the array above with surrounding quotes
   // get the username field and add to the array above with surrounding quotes
  $array3[] = $row[7]; // get the username field and add to the array above with surrounding quotes
  }
?>
 <select> <option>
<?

foreach($array1 as $it=>$ss){
      foreach($array3 as $rr=>$vv){
         if ($it==$rr) {

         echo str_replace(',', '<option value="'.$ss.'">', $vv .'</option>');

         }


       }
}

 ?>
</select>
```

Comment: First of all use the `mysqli_extension` as `mysql` is deprecated one ! and then what is your table_name because you mentioned it as **profile**  in query and **users_table** in the comments.

Comment: What you have is a database in dire need of normalization. Create a second table, where you add the ID of the user / doctor, and one column for "no_ana" and one for "name_pr" and then transfer each single one into a row. That way, you will have three of them linked to the user you show here - all with the same ID, but different "no_ana" and "name_pr" content.

Comment: table name ==> profile

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your data comes in as `11,7,10` from a `multiple option or a checkbox as an array`

Do a loop from the incoming form data from the `array $no_ana` at the user form

```
foreach($no_ana as $key => $value){
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name (id, name, date, 
                    re_doctor, sex, age, no_ana, etc)
              VALUES ($val1, $val2, $val3, $val4, 
                    $val5, $val6, $value, $etc");
}
```

insert this code snippet to your script and test it out.

Here is how you do a multiple attribute

```
 <select multiple name="name_pr[]">
  <option value="11">11- HbA1C</option>
  <option value="7">10- O"Solivan Test</option>
  <option value="10">7 - Ramdam Blood Glocose</option>
</select>
```